# Do I need gaps in a pile of rack servers with no rack cabinet?

Tags: hosting, rack

I have seen [Do I need to leave gaps in a standard server rack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56786/do-i-need-to-leave-gaps-in-a-standard-server-rack) and my question is similar but different:

I have several rack servers (DELL 2850 mostly) but do not have a rack structure. Can I simply put one server on the top of another without having cool issues? (a pile of servers without putting them in a rack cabinet, just on the top of a desk one above the other)

I know rack cabinets allow some space between servers, even if you dont have gaps between them. What I am asking is just to put one on top of the other, with no vertical space at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are designed to vent front and rear. Stacking them is not going to make them any hotter or cooler than if they were in an actual rack.